# Audioplayer controls on lock screen

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I have a simple add using audioplayer 0.5.2 to load audio from urls (radios) and play them on the app. I solved the background playing issue in iOS but -- on lock screen  -- the audio controls do not appear. Is there a way with this or another flutter audio package to display the audio controls (play/ stop forward back) on iOS ?

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this issue?

Comment: @Riswan yes with this package https://github.com/alexelisenko/audio_player_service